# Ayuda con una pregunta sobre error stack overflow al llamar una clase desde otra

Tags: discusión, revisión-de-pregunta

Hace tiempo hice [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/13716/227), seguro que estaba mal planteada, pues fue votada negativamente.

La pregunta que quiero hacer es esta

> ## StackOverFlow al llamar una clase desde otra
>
> Tengo un frame llamado ***VentanaAgrContacto*** el tiene campos como ***JTextField*** encapsulados que utilizo en un método ***Guardar*** que tengo en otra clase llamada ***Controlador***, esta a su vez está en otro paquete.
>
> Lo que sucede es que llamo tanto a ***VentanaAgrContacto*** como a ***Controlador*** recursivamente.
>
> en otras palabras, en ***VentanaAgrContacto*** llamo a ***Controlador*** para llamar el método ***Guardar*** y, en ***Controlador*** llamo a ***VentanaAgrContacto*** para acceder a los campos.
>
> Todo esto que les digo me produce un ***StackOverFlowError*** por el tipo de recursión que hago.
>
> Lo que quisiera que me explicaran es como puedo evitar este tipo error al llamar una clase desde otra y viceversa o si estoy aplicando mal la lógica.

¿Les parece que está bien formulada la pregunta?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primero que nada, el título debe ser una pregunta. Esto ayudará a que se comprenda qué problema tienes mucho antes de tan siquiera leer el cuerpo de la pregunta.

Segundo, yo diría que si tu pregunta es sobre código, entonces incluyas el código relevante para reproducir tu problema. Es un sitio donde los lectores somos *programadores, desarrolladores, ingenieros en sistemas de información, sistemas informáticos, software, etc*.

Alguien que está acostumbrado a leer código, entonces debes comunicarte en ese lenguaje. Así como una imagen ayuda más que 1000 palabras, tu código ayuda más que su descripción.

Con esto en mente, te recomiendo revisar [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Luego que escribas *un MVCE (siglas en inglés para código mínimo, completo y verificable)*, tendrás lo siguiente:

1. Aumenta tu capacidad para aprender a isolar los problemas.
2. Aumenta tu capacidad para comprender mejor el problema y explicar sus causas.
3. Aumenta tu capacidad de ser conciso al explicar algún tema en particular.
4. Permite a los lectores entender y reproducir tu problema para facilitar la atención.

Por ejemplo, basado en la descripción que brindas, el contenido podría cambiar a:

> #### ¿Cómo tener una referencia circular entre clases y evitar StackOverflow error?
>
> Tengo el siguiente grupo de clases:
>
> ```java
>     package paquete1;
>     
>     public class VentanaAgrContacto {
>         JTextField campo;
>     }
>     
>     package paquete2;
>
>     public class Controlador {
>     
>     }
> ```
>
> <strike>Lo que sucede es que llamo tanto a VentanaAgrContacto como a Controlador recursivamente.</strike> (mostrar cómo haces esto en el código).
>
> Al ejecutar esto, veo que se produce un `StackOverFlowError` por el tipo de recursión que hago.
>
> > > Muestra *el stacktrace relevante (la lista de errores que ayudarían a resolver el problema)*.
>
> Lo que quisiera que me explicaran es cómo puedo evitar este tipo de error al llamar una clase desde otra y viceversa o si estoy aplicando mal la lógica.

Comment: Gracias amigo, me agrada tu respuesta, y sí, escribir código en vez de explicar el problema así como poner una pregunta de titular hacen que la duda sea mas objetiva, nuevamente gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: No es que escribas código en vez de explicar el problema. Debes mencionar qué problema tienes **y** mostrar el código relevante para ver por qué te sucede el problema.

Comment: Si, entendí esa parte, ahora veo que lo escribí mal